# How does one show that $\cos {\left (\ln 2 \right )}\approx \frac{10}{13}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, approximation

How does one approximate the value of something like this?

Apparently Euler found the value of $\large \frac{2^i+2^{-i}}{2}\large $ [which equals $\cos {\left (\ln 2 \right )}$] to be close to $\frac{10}{13}$, which is correct upto the $5$th decimal place.

I came across this in P.J. Nahin's book *"An Imaginary Tale: The Story of $\sqrt {-1}$"*
[image: Have a look at the bottom of this page]

Comment: Without trying fancy ways of doing it: simply computing the first three terms in the power-series $\cos(\log(2)) = 1 - \frac{\log(2)^2}{2} + \frac{\log(2)^4}{24} + \ldots$ gives $\frac{10}{13} $ to an accuracy of $10^{-4}$ (and the error in the approximation is roughly $10^{-4}$).

Comment: Yes, it is an impressively good approximation: $\frac{10}{13}=0.769230 769230\dots,\cos\ln2=0.76923\ 8901363972\dots$

Comment: @Winther I guess that is the most probable way, but we are also approximating $\ln 2$.

Comment: You can alternately expand about $\pi/4$, which is fairly close to $\ln(2)$, but because the odd terms are present, the convergence within the first few terms is not all that fast (4 correct decimal places requires 4 terms). As for the approximation of $\ln(2)$ you need about the same number of decimal places of $\ln(2)$ as you need of $\cos(\ln(2))$. To me it seems relevant that $\ln(2),\pi/4$ and $\sqrt{2}/2$ are all within $(0.69,0.79)$...

Comment: There are quickly converging continued fractions for $\log(2)$ that can give us very good rational approximations, see e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalLogarithmof2ContinuedFraction.html

Comment: @almagest I don't see where this is closely related.

Comment: @almagest How does that help us to hand-approximate $\cos(\ln(2))$?

Comment: Here is one way one could justify it: Using the continued fraction for $\log(2) = [0; 1, 2, 3, 1, 6, \ldots]$ up to the fifth term gives us the approximation $\log(2)  \approx \frac{9}{13}$. This is good to a few times $10^{-4}$. Next using the power-series for $\cos(x)$ mentioned above to $O(x^4)$ gives us $\cos(\log(2)) - \frac{10}{13} \approx \frac{3\cdot 53}{8\cdot 13^4}$ which is good to an accuracy $10^{-3}$. All these computations can easily be made by hand.

Comment: @Winther I don't think $\frac{9}{13}$ for $\ln2$ gets us close to Euler's accuracy however accurately we then approximate cos.

Comment: Is there a reference that associates Euler with this approximation?

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes have a look at the edited post.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, that's great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rational function $$\frac{18x}{x^2+4x+1}-2$$ is an extremely good approximation on $[\tfrac12,2]$ and substituting $x=2$ (or $x=\tfrac12$) gives $\tfrac{10}{13}$. I stumbled upon this by noting that  $$\frac1{1-\cos(\log(x))}= \frac2{(x-1)^2}+\frac2{x-1}+\frac13+O((x-1)^4)$$ and therefore that $$ \frac2{(x-1)^2}+\frac2{x-1}+\frac13$$ is a good approximation of $$\frac1{1-\cos(\log(x))}.$$

Comment: How is the function derived?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Added how I found it.

Comment: This function is the [Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) of $\cos(\log(x+1)$, shifted back by $1$, with $m=n=2$.

Comment: But it is unlikely that Euler used this method, considering it was developed long after he passed away.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Euler didn't use the term "Padé approximant" maybe but I have little doubt that he knew the rational function above. He was more than capable to come up which such beauties.